# ROS Programmable Drones/UAVs in the Market

Tags: ros, uav, drone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Does anyone have any recommendation for programmable drones (preferably ROS compatible) available in the market? For research purposes (mainly navigation problems) in a robotics lab?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224557/ros-programmable-drones/uavs-in-the-market/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2016-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using [Pixahwak](https://pixhawk.org/modules/pixhawk) running [APM](http://ardupilot.com/) or [PX4](http://dev.px4.io/) and [onboard computer](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php) running Ubuntu and ROS. [Mavros](http://wiki.ros.org/mavros) can be used for communicating between flight controller and onboard computer.

---

Originally posted by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) with karma: 214 on 2016-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2016-01-20**:
@crazymumu, Thanks. Is there any commercial drone in the market that has all these pieces? or do we need to build our own drone you suggest?

**Comment by [Kartal](https://answers.ros.org/users/25643/kartal/) on 2016-01-29**:
@crazymumu Can I use the same steps like for a Parrot AR-drone? http://ardrone-autonomy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
Or is there another way to build up a communication? I do have a quadcopter with pixhawk(APM) and onboard computer with Ubuntu/ROS.

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2016-01-31**:
You will at least need Parrot AR-Drone 1.0 or 2.0 quadrocopter if you want to use **ardrone_autonomy**. Based on what you have, Mavros is a better option.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2016-01-31**:
@crazymumu Any info about the commercial drones using Pixahawk?

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2016-02-29**:
3DR Solo is based on pixhawk and has onboard computer. But i do not know it is hackable or not. At least they support DroneKit, so you may tie telemetry channel to network (and then run mavros on other machine).

**Comment by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on 2016-06-01**:
@vooon can u please expand on your suggestion of using dronekit with mavros? Dronekit will connect to the solo and control it. What do you mean by tieing telemetry channel to network?

**Comment by [mfkj](https://answers.ros.org/users/38085/mfkj/) on 2018-10-18**:
Can you please define us about the names of drone instead of flight controller/auto pilots?